# Why use Docker images in production when already have VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, deployment

I am doing research on which is the most efficient way for serving a production app from a cloud hosting provider like DigitalOcean using linux as server platform. DigitalOcean provides VMs - called droplets. Common sense would be that the best way is to just deploy the app as is in the VM (droplet) provided. Docker containers surely bring an overhead that translates to slower response from the deployed app. I am not aware of any optimizations done by the cloud hosting providers to the docker containers running inside VMs.

Considering that the VMs can be configured with scripts to be identical as the Docker containers, does it make any sense to use Docker in production?

Answer (score 3):

The Docker ecosystem has a pretty nice set of tools for (re)building Docker containers from scratch according to a specification in a Dockerfile.

If the overhead is not critical to your application, or the app design is scalable by parallelizing, using the containers inside the VMs may still make sense because of development and maintenance convenience provided by the containers. If you need more performance, just add more parallel nodes...

But you're correct in that it might not be the right solution for everyone: if you already have the infrastructure in place for auto-building new VMs of the correct kind at will and are happy with it, you might already have the same convenience in a different way. Or if you don't need to run multiple instances in parallel, the convenience advantage might not be that big anyway.

Essentially, the aim is to make the production updates a no-brainer: "just stop the VM/container, throw the old one away, deploy this new VM image/container in its place, and restart. Repeat for however many VMs/containers you have running the same app in parallel."

Using a de-facto standard like Docker containers allows you to easily migrate from one service provider to another, if necessary. With a development infrastructure designed and optimized to effortlessly produce DigitalOcean droplets, you might have to rebuild parts of your development automation if you ever migrate away from DigitalOcean.

On the other hand, if single-node performance is a critical factor for your application, then the right answer might not be a cloud at all, but perhaps some form of traditional hosted or even on-premises server. It might also indicate that the app is a hasty adaptation of a traditional single-server design to the cloud world, and needs some further design work to really fit well in the cloud ecosystem, to take advantage of scalability and multi-node parallelism whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

i just recently begin with containers and docker. Its better because you could run containers everywhere, are lightweight arquitecture and can start up faster that an VM.
You can have many images from docker hub for build infrastructura.
For instance, if you need a Webserver with wordpres or LAMP you could just install the public image in docker hub and thats it

And next step, you could unsterstand the beautifull world of kubernetes.

I hope that answer it was usefull.